# Xcode 6 - Unknown type name 'NSString' / Expected identifier or '('

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

When I am running my project in Xcode 6, I am having many weird errors.

```
Parse Issue - Unknown type name 'NSString'
Format argument not an NSString
Could not build module Foundation
Could not build module QuartzCore
```

All of these errors occur in Apple's header files such as: CAMediaTiming.h, NSObjCRuntime.h,NSZone.h,NSObject.h, CALayer.h, etc.

Unfortunately, the answers in here: [ios - Parse Issues in NSObjCRuntime, NSZone, and NSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857765/ios-parse-issues-in-nsobjcruntime-nszone-and-nsobject) did not work for me.

How do you recommend I fix these errors?

Comment: I had a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351496/xcode-5-couldnt-build-module-cocoa-after-installing-xcode-6-beta-2

Comment: Were you able to eventually get your project to work using Xcode 6?

Comment: Yes. The project was working fine again. It seemed like only Xcode had been damaged in a way.

Comment: Which .c or .m file causes these warnings? What does that code look like?

Comment: I got this obnoxious bug once for NSString. Try adding #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> in the file in which you are getting the bug. I know its vague but it did fixed my issue.

Comment: This worked for me
    #import <objc/NSObject.h>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem was that I had some `.c` files in my project, apparently Xcode 6 doesn't like `.c` files.

I changed the extension of the `.c` files to `.m` and Xcode 6 is happy again!

Comment: Using .mm instead of .m allows for both cpp and obj-c.

Comment: Thanks. Hard to imagine why this happens though. Objective c and plain .c files should be compatible, since Objective C is supposed to be a superset of C, at least last time I read a book around its origins.

Comment: Thanks, it saved a complete day for me.

Answer (score 24):

You can get this error if you have a PrefixHeader file that imports Objective-C code and also some plain C files in your project, because the C files try to import the Objective-C.

To fix, wrap your objective-c imports like this :

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <OOObjectiveCClass.h>
#endif
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! +1!

Comment: Thank u so much, Its save lots of my efforts.

Comment: Superbbb... 100% Correct Answer

Answer (score 7):

See if the Prefix Header file path is correctly placed under Build Settings tab. See the complete answer at the following link.

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828208/unknown-type-name-nserror-and-others)

Answer (score 1):

I use Xcode 8.3.3,I also encounter this problem，and I solve this issue by selecting the file and in the right panel in Xcode in the Identity and Type part choose Type to Objective-C++.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever else runs into this silly error (that you can waste a lot of time trying to solve.)

In my case I had:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

in the `.hh` file.

When I moved it (along with any other Obj-C imports) into my `.mm` file, the problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try deleting the Samples folder in the FacebookSDK folder (and then deleting the reference to it in Xcode.