# unqualified-id , Unkown type name ‘NSString’

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, callkit

I had a problem when I have tried to integrate Speakerbox project in my project. 
when i compile my project , the compiler told me there are compile errors in **NSObjCRuntion.h** ,**NSZone.h**, **NSObject.h** ! 
like:
Unkown type name ‘NSString’,
Expected unqualified-id 
“Too many errors emitted”.
 what’s wrong? any help,thanks

Comment: it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003727/xcode-6-unknown-type-name-nsstring-expected-identifier-or/34074815

Comment: thx that's really helped me