# Unknown type name 'NSString' in Xcode 11

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode shows `Unknown type name 'NSString'` and other errors when I'm editing codes.

[image: Error messages]

There are C and Obj-C codes in my project. Though it shows these error when editing, the codes ***can run normally*** in the simulator or iPhone. And 'thanks to' the problem Xcode cannot autocomplete code normally.

What I have tried:

1. Quitted Xcode and restarted my Mac for times;
2. Changed all .c file into .m;
3. Changed all .c file's type to `Objective-C source` in Identity and Type.

But none of them work for me.

UPDATE 10/17: After I update my Mac to 10.15, the problems disappeared and everything goes normally.

TLPlayerSubViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TLMovieObject;
@class TLOverlayView;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

extern NSString *const TLSubViewDismissNotification;

@interface TLPlayerSubViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) TLOverlayView *playerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TLMovieObject *video;

- (void)playVideo;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

TLPlayerSubViewController.m

```
#import "TLPlayerSubViewController.h"
#import "TLOverlayView.h"
#import "TLMovieObject.h"

NSString *const TLSubViewDismissNotification = @"";

@interface TLPlayerSubViewController () <TLOverlayViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation TLPlayerSubViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerView];


}
```

I explain my question more clearly. Before the system update, I have already include/import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` in the .h file or .m file. It is strange that I NEVER modify ANY codes but update the system to the latest version and then the error message disappeared.

Notice that:

1. Though the error messages shows, the project can run normally. I don't think missing .h file the code can still run normally.
2. I use FFMpeg in my project and there are some .c file in it. I try to change THOSE .c file into .m file but no works. I write Objective-C codes in .m file(as the picture shows), not .c file.

I wonder if it is a bug in Xcode 11 or the system...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 - Unknown type name 'NSString' / Expected identifier or '('](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003727/xcode-6-unknown-type-name-nsstring-expected-identifier-or)

Comment: Please show the import or include statement where you include Foundation. Also how can `NSString*` and `@interface` and `@implementation` appear in a _.c_ file? This is Objective-C. Is there a corresponding _.h_ file? Do you include/import it? Prove it, and show the _.h_ file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if ur code is Objective-C and its file's extension should be .m(in most case)
for NSString and the ones with NS prefix, check the source code file whether it has headers like `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` and `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`, also check the project has these link libraies.

Foundation for the NSString and basic class definitions

UIKit for the UI prefix class definitions. e.g. UIViewController(which has a view property)

Answer (score 0):

set compile source as "according to file type" for all builds and targets