# Could not build module Cocoa in xcode 8

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode8, quicklook

I am trying to write a simple QuickLook plugin based on apple dev docs and [this blog post](https://aleksandrov.ws/2014/02/25/osx-quick-look-plugin-development/).

But as son as I add

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

in the beginning of the *.c file I get an error: **Could not build module Cocoa**

Which looks like this:
[image]

I've also tried to add thos libe as a deps in the project, like this:
[image]
with no luck.

I've already tried to reinstall xcode. Also I've read those: [iOS : Could not build module <framework-name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717956/ios-could-not-build-module-framework-name), 
[Xcode 5 Couldn't build module Cocoa after installing Xcode 6 beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351496/xcode-5-couldnt-build-module-cocoa-after-installing-xcode-6-beta-2).

I have xcode 8.2 and OS 10.11.

Comment: #import or #include? (it should be #import)

Comment: @DDP both don't work.

Comment: And just to check also: this is a .m (objective-c) file not a .c?

Comment: @DDP it's a C. could not rename C to M.

Comment: Yes, renaming c->m in xcode helped!

Comment: Great @shershen. I'll submit that as an answer in case it is useful for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa frameworks should be `#import`'d rather than `#include`'d.  However, #import requires an Objective-C file (.m).